# Image elements are skipping while converting XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm having the image element, its skipping while I convert the XSL Tranformation, Please make it possible to change in my provided code. because the this code is working well with lot of input files,

My Input XML:

```
<Body>
<h1>Local</h1>
<p>Early</p>
<h2>Home</h2>
<h3>Medicines</h3>
<p>Home</p>
<h3>General</h3>
<p>
<img alt="Man" height="187" width="300" class="right" src="https://tneb.com" />
</p>
<ul>
<li>
<p>Itching</p>
</li>
<li>
<p>pack</p>
</li>
</ul>
</Body>
```

XSLT 2.0 I have used and I converted by using the saxon - PE 9.6.0.7,

```
 <xsl:template match="Body">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*[normalize-space()]" group-starting-with="h1">
         <topic outputclass="">
            <xsl:attribute name="id">topic_<xsl:number count="h1 | h2 | h3 | h4 | h5"/></xsl:attribute>
            <title outputclass="">
               <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
            </title>

            <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group() except ." group-starting-with="h2 | div[@data-swiq-type='callout-box']">
               <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="self::h2">
                     <topic outputclass="TOPIC-Section">
                        <xsl:attribute name="id">topic_<xsl:number count="h1 | h2 | h3 | h4 | h5 | div"/></xsl:attribute>
                        <title outputclass="Section">
                           <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
                        </title>

                        <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group() except ." group-starting-with="h3 | div[@data-swiq-type='callout-box']">
                           <xsl:choose>
                              <xsl:when test="self::h3">
                                 <topic outputclass="TOPIC-Sub-Section">
                                    <xsl:attribute name="id">topic_<xsl:number count="h1 | h2 | h3 | h4 | h5 | div"/></xsl:attribute>
                                    <title outputclass="Sub-Section">
                                       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
                                    </title>

                                    <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group() except ." group-starting-with="h4 | div[@data-swiq-type='callout-box']">
                                       <xsl:choose>
                                          <xsl:when test="self::h4">
                                             <topic outputclass="TOPIC-Sub-Section">
                                                <xsl:attribute name="id">topic_<xsl:number count="h1 | h2 | h3 | h4 | h5 | div"/></xsl:attribute>
                                                <title outputclass="Sub-Section">
                                                   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
                                                </title>

                                                <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group() except ." group-starting-with="h5 | div[@data-swiq-type='callout-box']">
                                                   <xsl:choose>
                                                      <xsl:when test="self::h5">
                                                         <topic outputclass="TOPIC-Sub-Section">
                                                            <xsl:attribute name="id">topic_<xsl:number count="h1 | h2 | h3 | h4 | h5 | div"/></xsl:attribute>
                                                            <title outputclass="Sub-Section">
                                                               <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
                                                            </title>


                                                            <body><xsl:apply-templates select="current-group() except ."/></body>
                                                         </topic>
                                                      </xsl:when>
                                                      <xsl:when test="self::div[@data-swiq-type='callout-box']">
                                                         <topic outputclass="TOPIC-Box">
                                                            <xsl:attribute name="id">topic_<xsl:number count="h1 | h2 | h3 | h4 | h5 | div"/></xsl:attribute>
                                                            <title><xsl:value-of select="h5"/></title>
                                                            <body><xsl:apply-templates/></body>
                                                         </topic>
                                                      </xsl:when>
                                                      <xsl:otherwise>
                                                         <body><xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/></body>
                                                      </xsl:otherwise>
                                                   </xsl:choose>
                                                </xsl:for-each-group>

                                                </topic>
                                          </xsl:when>
                                          <xsl:when test="self::div[@data-swiq-type='callout-box']">
                                             <topic outputclass="TOPIC-Box">
                                                <xsl:attribute name="id">topic_<xsl:number count="h1 | h2 | h3 | h4 | h5 | div"/></xsl:attribute>
                                                <title><xsl:value-of select="h4"/></title>
                                                <body><xsl:apply-templates/></body>
                                             </topic>
                                          </xsl:when>
                                          <xsl:otherwise>
                                             <body><xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/></body>
                                          </xsl:otherwise>
                                       </xsl:choose>

                                    </xsl:for-each-group>

                                 </topic>                      
                              </xsl:when>
                              <xsl:when test="self::div[@data-swiq-type='callout-box']">
                                 <topic outputclass="TOPIC-Box">
                                    <xsl:attribute name="id">topic_<xsl:number count="h1 | h2 | h3 | h4 | h5 | div"/></xsl:attribute>
                                    <title><xsl:value-of select="h3"/></title>
                                    <body><xsl:apply-templates/></body>
                                 </topic>
                              </xsl:when>
                              <xsl:otherwise>
                                 <body><xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/></body>
                              </xsl:otherwise>
                           </xsl:choose>

                        </xsl:for-each-group>
                     </topic>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:when test="self::div[@data-swiq-type='callout-box']">
                     <topic outputclass="TOPIC-Box">
                        <xsl:attribute name="id">topic_<xsl:number count="h1 | h2 | h3 | h4 | h5 | div"/></xsl:attribute>
                        <title outputclass=""><xsl:value-of select="h2 | h3 | h4 | h5"/></title>
                        <body><xsl:apply-templates/></body>
                     </topic>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                     <body><xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/></body>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
               </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
         </topic>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="p">
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="not(text()[normalize-space(.)] | child::*)"/>
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <p outputclass="Body_text_no_indent">
               <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </p>            
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="img">
      <xsl:element name="image">
            <xsl:if test="@imageid">
               <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="@imageid"/></xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="@title">
               <xsl:attribute name="xtrf"><xsl:apply-templates select="@title"/></xsl:attribute>
             </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="@src">
               <xsl:attribute name="href">
                  <xsl:variable name="resolutionremove">
                  <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(@src, '/')[position() = last() - 2 or position() = last()]" separator="_"/>
                  </xsl:variable>
                  <xsl:value-of select="replace($resolutionremove, '.([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)', '')"/>
               </xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="@alt">
            <xsl:attribute name="alt"><xsl:apply-templates select="@alt"/></xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
         <xsl:if test="@height">
            <xsl:attribute name="height"><xsl:value-of select="@height"/></xsl:attribute>
         </xsl:if>
         <xsl:if test="@width">
            <xsl:attribute name="width"><xsl:value-of select="@width"/></xsl:attribute>
         </xsl:if>
         <xsl:if test="@align">
            <xsl:attribute name="align"><xsl:value-of select="@align"/></xsl:attribute>
         </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="@data-image">
               <xsl:attribute name="base">data-image(<xsl:value-of select="@data-image"/>)</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>            
         <xsl:attribute name="outputclass">Image_Ref</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ul" priority="0">
      <ul outputclass="">
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </ul>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="ul/li" priority="0">
      <li outputclass="List_Bullet">
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][self::ul]" mode="wrap"/>
      </li>
   </xsl:template>
```

While I converting, the image element is getting skip, if I used this img inside the list tag means its coming. Can anyone please provide me the suggestion for this. Please make the change in the provide code of Body template. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="*[normalize-space()]" group-starting-with="h1">
```

to

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="*[node()]" group-starting-with="h1">
```